# How to alter Postgres column type from ENUM to VARCHAR

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with type ENUM. The possible values are "public, private, followers".

How can I convert the column type to varchar without losing the values?

The postgres version is 9.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
alter table table_name alter column col_name  TYPE varchar;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You wont loose the values by the conversion, but you will loose the restriction on the values that can be entered. If you don't want that you'll have to create a check constraint on the revised column.